# Правописание с «не» в моем предложении

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные, причастия

*Конфигурация забора значится некапитальной и не блокирующей доступ жителей к дому.*
Правильно в данном случае написание слов «некапитальный» и «не блокирующий»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Не блокирующей" раздельно, потому что есть зависимое слово "доступ";

"не капитальной" раздельно, потому что "капитальный" - относительное прилагательное.

*Конфигурация забора значится не капитальной и не блокирующей доступ жителей к дому.*

Comment: Приветствую! Редко вы к нам заглядываете, Галина. Я соскучилась по вашему особенному языку. * * * Имею сомнение: капитальный — это качественное прилагательное.

Comment: А через сравнительную степень? Эта стена капитальнее той? О_о

Comment: Уф-фуф... Но краткая-то форма есть: И все труды Энгельса как бы не вполне **капитальны** и в известном смысле представляют собой добавочную ренту... [Михаил Эпштейн. Ленин-Сталин // «Родник», 1989] И антонимы есть.

Comment: Привет, привет!  Это вопрос сложный, философический. Слово многозначное, но (из словаря Кузнецова): К-ая стена (основная стена здания, сооружения, служащая опорой для покрытия). На качественный признак мало похоже. А вообще это специальный термин, а специальные люди могут его писать по своему понятию  в каждом конкретном случае. Например; https://www.zemvopros.ru/page_12673.htm  Но именно здесь я не исключаю раздельное написание,  Многое от текста зависит (какая у них там терминология).

Comment: Безотносительно к данному предложению, думаю, что капитальный – качеств. прил. Чтобы относиться к этой группе, прилагательному необязательно иметь все признаки и свойства, достаточно одного, а у капитального имеется даже больше: наречие – капитально, существительное – капитальность, степени сравнения – капитальнее, капитальнейший, антонимы – поверхностный, второстепенный, несущественный, ну и краткая форма. // Конечно, есть прилагательные, в разных контекстах относящиеся к разным группам

Comment: Ну это Викисловарь рассматривает как качественное. На сайте Части.ру( открытый институт филологии) как относительное. А вообще согласен с Sharon.

Comment: Серж, я сейчас вот что думаю. Термин "капитальный"имеет целый перечень признаков, и его нельзя заменить одним прилагательным (качественным или относительным), поэтому все рассуждения на эту тему просто не имеют смысла.